# In cells populated with VB Font Color not recognized by another function

Tags: excel, vba

I have created some vb code that distributes the Cost of an item up between 4 columns. The 4 columns content will always equal 0. Whichever of the columns is actively clicked gets the cost of the item multiplied by -75% , and the negative number is formatted already to be red. The other 3 columns get the cost of the item multiplied by .25% and formatted as black.
This has been working to catalogue estate items for distribution to beneficiaries. I wish to be able to count the columns by the red colored text (which in turn will let me know how many items each person receives)
Now I have added some functions that I didn't write but copied from a site. I have checked the CountCellByFontColor and on any other columns I can manually choose a font color and it does get detected and works perfectly. 
If I use this function on my 4 columns that have VB populating the content the function does not seem to recognize the red texted as red texted. If I click on the cell and change it manually to any color but red it does recognize and count it. Otherwise it just counts every cell in the column whether black or red.
Is there any way to fix this easily? I don't want to have to change a cell in every row to another color.

Here is a code snippet for my code and the copied function. I do want to re-iterate that the function to count the colored cells works perfectly everywhere but on my vb calculating columns . Thank you

```
Case "4"
       'Me.Unprotect
        'MsgBox Target.Address

        RowNumber = Target.Cells.Row
       ' MsgBox "RowNumber " & RowNumber
       'Debug.Print "test " & Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value


        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value * 0.25
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Font.Color = vbBlack
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value * 0.25
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Font.Color = vbBlack
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 7).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value * 0.25
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 7).Font.Color = vbBlack

        Debug.Print "test of assign " & Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value * 0.75)
        Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Font.Color = vbRed
```

And this is portion of the Code that doesn't recognise the red

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
Dim indRefColor As Long
Dim cellCurrent As Range
Dim cntRes As Long

Application.Volatile
cntRes = 0
indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
For Each cellCurrent In rData
    If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
        cntRes = cntRes + 1
    End If
Next cellCurrent

CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

Comment: Are the numbers formatted red with conditional formatting? Or is the red solely coming from `Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Font.Color = vbRed`?

Comment: It might be better and easier to test for negative and positive numbers instead of a colour

Comment: Yes Conditionally formatted by Case 1 to 4. as in the code above.,

Comment: Yes, Possibly I can filter by negative numbers. I never thought of that

Comment: That code is different from conditional formatting.

Comment: Oh, I am not that familiar with excel. which is why I had to copy the function for counting. Is conditional formatting set somewhere else?  I don't think I have conditional formatting then.

Comment: [This is conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Now that I think of it.  When I format the cells as Currency I chose the red text for negative numbers. Is that Conditional formatting?

Comment: OK no, I have not set up conditional formatting.

Comment: I cannot filter by negative numbers because there are a lot of items with no value so every column pays or gets 0. But one is still red because I could then see who got the item.

Comment: Correction. Any Item that is worth 0. Still is given to a column which will according to the vb posted. Still say 0 but in VBRed. The other 3 columns will be black and also say 0. So I cannot filter by countif (....<0). Need to find a way to countif font is VBRed.

Comment: I guess it must be because the font color is chosen in VBA. It just doesn't recognise it. If no one who has read this has a solution I will likely go through each column and change the red one to green as a workaround. It leaves room for error though.